# Reference to type 'IAuthorizeData' claims it is defined in 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization', but it could not be found

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-core-3.0, tag-helpers

I have an Asp.Net Core 2.2 application. When I migrate to Asp.Net Core 3.0, I'm getting the below error:

> Reference to type 'IAuthorizeData' claims it is defined in
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization', but it could not be found

I'm using `TagHelperSamples.Authorization` nuget package to optionally render portion of HTML based on user rights and roles.

I'm using the `asp-authorize` tag helpers from the above nuget package to show menu if user is authorized as shown below:

`<div asp-authorize class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">`

These tag helpers is creating the error on building the project.

I tried adding `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization` in `_ViewImports.cshtml` but that doesn't work.

Any helps/suggestions on how to fix this or any workarounds?

Comment: You might have missed some nuget packages which will also need updating. In the move from 2.2 to 3 some things got moved around, so the class you're looking for might be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TagHelperSamples.Authorization` does not fit for asp.net core 3.0 yet,refer to

https://github.com/dpaquette/TagHelperSamples/issues/77

You could just remove the package and manually create your authorize tag helper class based on [source code](https://github.com/dpaquette/TagHelperSamples/blob/master/TagHelperSamples/src/TagHelperSamples.Authorization/AuthorizeTagHelper.cs) in asp.net core 3.0 project:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Asp3identityCore.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "asp-authorize")]
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "asp-authorize,asp-policy")]
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "asp-authorize,asp-roles")]
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "asp-authorize,asp-authentication-schemes")]
    public class AuthorizationPolicyTagHelper : TagHelper, IAuthorizeData
    {
        private readonly IAuthorizationPolicyProvider _policyProvider;
        private readonly IPolicyEvaluator _policyEvaluator;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public AuthorizationPolicyTagHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IAuthorizationPolicyProvider policyProvider, IPolicyEvaluator policyEvaluator)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
            _policyProvider = policyProvider;
            _policyEvaluator = policyEvaluator;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the policy name that determines access to the HTML block.
        /// </summary>
        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-policy")]
        public string Policy { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a comma delimited list of roles that are allowed to access the HTML  block.
        /// </summary>
        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-roles")]
        public string Roles { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets a comma delimited list of schemes from which user information is constructed.
        /// </summary>
        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-authentication-schemes")]
        public string AuthenticationSchemes { get; set; }

        public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var policy = await AuthorizationPolicy.CombineAsync(_policyProvider, new[] { this });

            var authenticateResult = await _policyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(policy, _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext);

            var authorizeResult = await _policyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(policy, authenticateResult, _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext, null);

            if (!authorizeResult.Succeeded)
            {
                output.SuppressOutput();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the TagHelperSamples.Authorization package to support ASP.NET Core 3.0. Upgrading to the latest package version will fix your problem: https://www.nuget.org/packages/TagHelperSamples.Authorization/